# Can Google track me while I am logged via google to SO?

Tags: support, google

I am wondering if Google can track my surfing behaviour through Cookies while I am logged in to SO (I use my Google account to do so) ?

EDIT:

To clarify what I mean: Google offers the possibility to identify myself on various sites using my account. Does Google take advantage of that ? E.g. As long as I am logged in to SO, Google may track which sites I am visiting (aside of SO). I am not very concerned about what Google knows from me, but curious if the nice feature has its (hidden) price.

Comment: Dunno - ask the NSA.

Comment: Email them by writing an email, and saving it in your drafts.

Comment: Through cookies, perhaps not, but SO does I believe use Google Analytics so if Google cared about you as an individual (hint: they don't) they *could* theoretically build up a complete picture of your behaviour on the site.

Comment: Are you using google chrome? are you logged into it? have you noticed how your browser history follows you from computer to computer if logged into chrome at each?

Comment: They do of course track which sites you are logged into using google, past that though i doubt they have the ability to track you, other than through other sources such as analytics.

Answer (score 23):

SO uses Google analytics, so yes, they could determine what content on SO you're accessing through that.  If SO didn't use Google analytics, or if you block that request, then the fact that SO authenticates you through Google wouldn't necessarily mean that Google would be able to know what content you access on SO, they'd only be able to know that, and when, you authenticate with SO, not what goes on afterward you've authenticated.

Comment: Not completely true.  SO uses scripts hosted on Google's "googleapis.com" CDN as well as images hosted on Google's "googleusercontent.com" domain.  They get many chances to track you.  What do you think all this free stuff is for?  :)

Comment: *`s/could/do/`*

Comment: @radium However those things can track even users that log in via other OpenIDs, so they are unrelated to the question.